# When is it best to encrypt a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, encryption

I have a form where users can change their password and it gets stored in an SQL database. On form submission, the page submits to itself via POST. 
My question is, is it best to encrypt the password field on the client side (javascript) or on the server side (PHP), or both?

Comment: if the data is transferred using https, then server side encryption will be enough

Comment: did you mean hash not encrypt and the is SERVERSIDE, and post it via ssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form submission should be via SSL.  If you do that, then there is no need to encrypt on the client as the SSL will protect it in transit.

On the server, you need to develop a general security policy for how you store passwords.  A good way to store them is to only store some sort of secure hash and never store the actual password.  When a password is to be checked it is sent under SSL to the server, then on the server it is hashed and compared to the secure hash stored in the DB.  If they match, then the password check validates.  This means that even if your DB is compromised, no actual passwords are ever stolen.

You can use encryption before storing the actual password in the database, but this requires keeping the encryption method/key secure so that a hacker that might break into your DB couldn't then decrypt the passwords.  While this can be "secure" when done right, it has more potential vulnerabilities than only storing a hash and never storing the actual password and can also be compromised from the inside by employees who have access to both the DB and the encryption method/key who can then steal passwords.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light on me. I started reading into security and there is a lot than meets the eye haha!